# Appending multiplelines or "nodes" to an XML document correctly

Tags: xml, powershell

Lets say I have an `.xml` that currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<button backcol="none" display="label" label_pos="right" separate="yes" textcol="none">
  <label>MultiLine</label>
  <tip>Opens an Explorer window for the current folder</tip>
  <icon1>#folder</icon1>
  <function type="normal">
    <instruction>Hello 0</instruction>
  </function>
</button>
```

I would like to use Powershell to replace any  "instruction" nodes the input has, so an output of the above xml could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<button backcol="none" display="label" label_pos="right" separate="yes" textcol="none">
  <label>MultiLine</label>
  <tip>Opens an Explorer window for the current folder</tip>
  <icon1>#folder</icon1>
  <function type="normal">
    <instruction>Hello 1</instruction>
    <instruction>Hello 2</instruction>
    <instruction>Hello 3</instruction>
  </function>
</button>
```

I wrote a function to achieve this:

```
function DopusML {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
      )

    Process{
        $OutXML    = "C:\Temp\MultiLine.dcf"
        $MultiLine = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Temp\MultiLine.dcf")
    
        $InputObject -split "\n" | foreach-object {
            $CurrentLine = $_
            select-Xml -Xml $MultiLine -XPath "//button[label='MultiLine']//instruction" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml = "$CurrentLine"}
        }
        $MultiLine.Save($OutXML)
    }
}
```

Doing Something like:

```
"Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3" | DopusML
```

Gives me the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<button backcol="none" display="label" label_pos="right" separate="yes" textcol="none">
  <label>MultiLine</label>
  <tip>Opens an Explorer window for the current folder</tip>
  <icon1>#folder</icon1>
  <function type="normal">
    <instruction>Hello 3</instruction>
  </function>
</button>
```

Meaning only the last line is saved, instead of all the lines
I thing my propblem lies at:

`select-Xml -Xml $MultiLine -XPath "//button[label='MultiLine']//instruction" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml = "$CurrentLine"}`

so I tried:

`select-Xml -Xml $MultiLine -XPath "//button[label='MultiLine']//instruction" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml += "$CurrentLine"}`

As well as:

`select-Xml -Xml $MultiLine -XPath "//button[label='MultiLine']//instruction" | % {$_.Node.InnerXml += @($CurrentLine)}`

---

The articles I have been reading dont really go into depth into this issue and am out of idea as well.

Any help or ideas, would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

As per your comment, I have added a switch `-Append` to the function.
**without** specifying this when calling the function, all already present  nodes will first be removed.
**with** specifying switch `-Append` when calling the function, new nodes will be added, leaving already present nodes untouched

```powershell
function DopusML {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$InputObject,

        [switch]$Append
    )

    $file = "D:\Test\MultiLine.dcf"  # should this be hardcoded?
    # load the xml file. This way, you are ensured to get the file encoding correct
    $xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
    $xml.Load($file)

    if (!$Append) {
        # you want to first remove the already present instruction nodes
        $xml.DocumentElement.function.ChildNodes | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object {
            [void]$_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
        }
    }
    foreach ($string in ($InputObject -split '\r?\n')) {
        $newNode = $xml.CreateElement('instruction')
        $newNode.InnerText = $string
        [void]$xml.DocumentElement.function.AppendChild($newNode)
    }

    $xml.Save($file)
}
```

Then calling it with

```powershell
@"
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
"@ | DopusML
```

would result in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<button backcol="none" display="label" label_pos="right" separate="yes" textcol="none">
  <label>MultiLine</label>
  <tip>Opens an Explorer window for the current folder</tip>
  <icon1>#folder</icon1>
  <function type="normal">
    <instruction>Hello 1</instruction>
    <instruction>Hello 2</instruction>
    <instruction>Hello 3</instruction>
  </function>
</button>
```

Comment: this is really great, I tested it and sure enough it works smooth. while trying your solution I noticed appending new instruction nodes to existing instruction nodes is a bad design, is there any chance all existing instruction nodes can first be removed? or just overwrite the old instructions  with the new ones?

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89 Please see the edited code. Now the function has an `-Append` switch, meaning that if you do **not** use that, all existing instruction nodes will first be removed before new ones are added. If you want to add new nodes leaving the existing subnodes intact, call the function like `$multilineString | DopusML -Append`

Comment: Its working even better than I thought now. StackOverflow is a god send, Thank you so much. Its always a pleasure to see how actual proffesionals like to approach things. I will take a close look at your code on its own as well